# Why does ES6 define map.length==0?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

**Map.length**

The value of the length property is 0.

What is the use case for this? I understand why `Map.size` is semantically correct. But surely a `Map.length` that almost always returns the "wrong" answer is a bad idea, especially if there's an oversight migrating code from ES5.  Is there a way to force an error when this is used?

Comment: [Here's the relevant part of the spec, too](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-map-constructor)

Comment: It says `Map.length` is `0`.  Not that the `.length` property of a `new Map()` is `0`.  Try: `var m = new Map();  console.log(m.length, m.size, Map.length);`.

Comment: Still doesn't explain *why* `Map.length === 0` though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Constructors in JavaScript are regular functions, and the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) property of a function corresponds to the number of formal parameters expected by the function, which is 0 in the case of `Map`.

Contrast this with `RegExp.length`, which is 2, because the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor expects two parameters (pattern and flags).

Comment: That's not quite consistent though, because the `flags` parameter to `RegExp` is optional, as is `iterable` to `Map`, so `Map.length` ought to be 1 by that logic?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Actually native functions – unlike user-defined functions – don't even have a formal definition, and so the `length` property is simply specified by the ECMAScript standard, and this specification may certainly take into account compatibility issues over real usage concerns. The _spirit_, though, is the same.

Comment: @JamesThorpe FWIW: The spec describes it as _"the typical number of arguments expected by the function"_

Comment: Thanks both - I realise the JS spec has had a... vibrant history - _"typical number"_ sounds about right!

Comment: Interesting that Object.length==1 and Map.length==0, when they both optionally take one parameter.